# How can I use a instance variable to accomplish the same task?

Tags: ruby, hash

Here I use a global variable to store a list because I can't figure out how I can keep ahold of a list long enough to check its values for duplicates.

```
$list = []
def hand_out_gift(name)
  if $list.include?name 
    puts "No present for you"
  else 
    $list.push(name)
  end
end

hand_out_gift("Peter")
hand_out_gift("Alison")
hand_out_gift("John")
hand_out_gift("Maria")
hand_out_gift("Peter")
```

How can I accomplish the same check with an instance variable?

Comment: If it's the whole script then simply by using instance variables, they should work.

Comment: replace `$` with `@` that makes global variables instance variables

Comment: @SergioTulentsev When I declare list(instance) as an empty hash, it rewrites the hash every time the code is ran which is the problem i'm facing. How can I run the code without having to declass list as an empty hash each time?

Comment: @bjhaid thanks for this. Before your comment I thought that instance variables can only exist within a method!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby works best when you approach your problem using object oriented code.

More often than not, you'll want to think of your data as objects with their own properties and methods, rather than as consequences of data structures that reside in the scope you're working on (global in your example, or local if you edit it per the other answer).

Here's a convoluted example to illustrate:

```
class Party
  def initialize(members = nil)
    @members = {}
    invite(*members) if members
  end

  def members
    @members.values
  end

  def invite(*members)
    members = Hash[members.map { |member|
      if member.is_a?(Member)
        [member.name.downcase, member]
      else
        [member.downcase, Member.new(member)]
      end
    }]
    @members = members.merge(@members)
  end

  def find(member)
    if member.is_a?(Member)
      key = member.name
    else
      key = member
    end
    @members[key.downcase]
  end
end
```

We could define a member object alongside.

```
class Member
  attr_reader :name, :gift

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def has_gift?
    !!@gift
  end

  def gift=(gift)
    raise if has_gift?
    @gift = gift
  end
end
```

and we could call that using:

```
members = ["Peter", "Alison", "John", "Maria"]
party = Party.new(members)
party.members.each { |m| m.gift = true }
party.find("Peter").gift = :foo
```

(Completely untested code, so you'll hopefully forgive the potential syntax error.)

In the above, Party is responsible for managing (and indexing) the list of members. Members, on its end, is responsible for checking if that member got a gift or not. To each his own properties, and assorted methods.

I could (should in fact) have used a Set object instead of a Hash in that Party object. Note how encapsulating this internal representation and never exposing it means you can later change it to a Set indeed, without any harmful effect for the rest of the code. The only change elsewhere would be the need to define how to hash a Member.

Comment: I appreciate this greatly. If i'm following you correctly here, you are saying that an object doesn't have to be a consequence of other object, but instead can have it's own methods and code blocks. Like where you passed a method and code block to the members hash in the invite method?

Comment: @gwapEs9: more or less, yeah. The output of your functions shouldn't a consequence of other data structures that live nearby. Instead, these data structures should be internal properties of an object, and the outside word shouldn't be able to even know the implementation details. Instead, your object should expose a set of methods that allow the world to tell it to do something with its properties, e.g. add members, list members, find a member, etc. And these properties will oftentimes be objects in their own right, with their own properties and methods, e.g. receive a gift.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a `global variable` and an `instance variable` is `global variables` start with `$` while `instance variables` start with `@` and `global variables` are globally accessible, while instance variables are only accessible to an instance of the object

```
@list = []
def hand_out_gift(name)
  if @list.include?name 
    puts "No present for you"
  else 
    @list.push(name)
  end
end

hand_out_gift("Peter")
hand_out_gift("Alison")
hand_out_gift("John")
hand_out_gift("Maria")
hand_out_gift("Peter")

@list # => ["Peter", "Alison", "John", "Maria"]
```

Comment: `@list` outside the method is different than `@list` inside one. If it's defined inside of the class, you'll get an error. Also, this example, even if correct, can be misleading, since it doesn't really point any difference between global and instance variables.

Comment: He did end his if else with an end. His syntax was correct, except for the global var.

Comment: @MarekLipka I have clarified my explanation on the difference between global and instance variables, and if you don't have a class they really behave almost same way

Comment: @snowe2010 sorry I did not see that, his indentation deceived me, I would update my answer